# Identifying a Japanese font

Tags: font-identification, japanese

can you please help me identify this font? the red one
[image]

couldn't find any font detector...

Answer (score 2):

I think these glyphs have been modified a bit. The tapering of the final strokes on the 巧 and 少 characters is particularly exaggerated.

Apart from that, the font looks rather similar to [リュウミン B-KL](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1302) by Morisawa:

[image: 機巧少女]

But having said that, Mincho-style fonts all look quite similar to one another. [Fontworks](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/) is another major Japanese font foundry that you could try.